# How do I make my plug-in work on duplicate HTML markup but operate separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I inherited Javascript and jQuery for a sliding belt (carousel) module.  Basically, left and right navigation arrows would appear to the sides of the belt if there were more slides to show.

The jQuery and Javascript code was originally a singleton, so I decided to convert it into a jQuery plug-in in case the belt HTML markup was instantiated more than once.  We have a CMS, so multiple belt modules theoretically could be placed on the same template.

Below is test page with two belts on the same page and the associated Javascript jQuery.  My problem is that when you click on the arrows or the slides, both belts respond instead of the belt I interacted with.

What I would like to do is when I attach my plug-in to a DIV, I want each belt to operate independently of each other (i.e keep its own local variables, functions, etc.).

I am not sure what I am missing here.  Can somebody point out my mistake and explain what I am doing wrong?  (You should be able to copy and paste the code into jsFiddle to see how it currently works.)

Thank you for reading.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Belt Test</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      div.belt { height: 95px; padding: 16px 0 6px 0; position: relative; width: 619px; }
      div.belt span.scrollLeft,
      div.belt span.scrollRight { display: none; padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; width: 48px; }
      div.belt span.scrollLeft { float: left; }
      div.belt span.scrollRight { float: right; }
      div.belt span.scrollLeft a, 
      div.belt span.scrollRight a { background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('http://img4.realsimple.com/static/i/gallery-sprite2.gif'); display: block; height: 24px; margin: 0 auto; outline: 0; width: 24px; text-decoration: none; }
      div.belt span.scrollLeft a { background-position: -3px -679px; }
      div.belt span.scrollRight a { background-position: -3px -650px; }
      div.belt span.scrollLeft a:hover { background-position: -3px -737px; text-decoration: none; }
      div.belt span.scrollRight a:hover { background-position: -3px -708px; text-decoration: none; }
      div.belt div.wrapper { height: 87px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 48px; position: relative; width: 522px; }
      div.belt ul { height:87px; left: 0px; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; }
      div.belt li { display:inline;float:left;padding:6px;}
      div.belt li.selected { border: 1px solid #0099fe; padding: 5px; }
      div.belt li a,
      div.belt li a:hover { outline:none; text-decoration:none; }
      div.belt li img { cursor: pointer; display: block; height: 75px; width: 75px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     (function($) {
       /** 
         * @description jQuery Belt plug-in - Add default global belt behavior to ul-style belt where each click on the belt is a page refresh.
         * This is a fixed belt with no customization allowed.  Attach this plug-in to the div encapsulating the UL.
         */
       $.fn.globalbelt = function() {

       /* Inside .each(), this keyword refers to current DOM object */
       return this.each(function() {

            /* We save a reference to the current div element and use it for traversal later */
            var self = this;

            /* Variable initialization */
            var slides = $('ul', self).find('li').size(), /* calc # of slides */
            pages = Math.ceil(slides / 6), /* calc # of pages */
            pageWidth = 522, /* width of one slide page */
            shiftDuration = 400, /* animation duration */
            currentPage = 1, /* current slide page */
            beltSize = slides * 87; /* sets the width of the entire belt */

            $('ul', self).css('width', beltSize + 'px');

            /* hides/shows scrolling arrows */
            setScrollButtons = function(){
                if (currentPage <= 1) {
                    $('.scrollLeft', self).hide();
                } else {
                    $('.scrollLeft', self).show();
                }
                if (currentPage >= pages) {
                    $('.scrollRight', self).hide();
                } else {
                    $('.scrollRight', self).show();
                }
            }

            /* hide / show buttons */
            setScrollButtons();

            /* Button event handler to scroll left */
            $('.scrollLeft a', self).click(function(event){
                currentPage--;
                setScrollButtons();

                $('ul', self).animate({ left: '+=' + pageWidth }, shiftDuration);

                return false;
            });

            /* Button event handler to scroll right */
            $('.scrollRight a', self).click(function(event){
                currentPage++;
                setScrollButtons();

                $('ul', self).animate({ left: '-=' + pageWidth }, shiftDuration);

                return false;
            });
    }); /* return this */
       } /* End plug-in */
 })(jQuery);

  /* Implicitly iterate and bind the plug in to each div that match the selector */
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.belt').globalbelt();
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="belt">
    <span class="scrollLeft">
        <a href="#">&#160;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="scrollRight">
        <a href="#">&#160;</a>
    </span>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="belt">
    <span class="scrollLeft">
        <a href="#">&#160;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="scrollRight">
        <a href="#">&#160;</a>
    </span>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/p/fi/39/03/54.jpg" title="1" alt="1" border="0" height="75" width="75" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved the var self = this; inside of the return this.each().  I updated the code above.  When I did this, the second belt responds normally, but not the first belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable without IDs. You just have to go up the DOM to find the specific div you are in, get the element object reference, and then only perform the action in that specific sub-tree of the DOM.

So in your click function you would add:

```
$('.scrollLeft a', self).click(function(event){
    var parentDiv = $(this).parents(".belt");
    currentPage--;
    setScrollButtons(parentDiv);
    //...rest of your code...
```

So now you have a reference to the specific belt element which you pass to your helper function. You can modify your helper function in the following way:

```
            setScrollButtons = function(parentDiv){
            if (currentPage <= 1) {
                parentDiv.find('.scrollLeft', self).hide();
            } else {
                parentDiv.find('.scrollLeft', self).show();
            }
            if (currentPage >= pages) {
                parentDiv.find('.scrollRight', self).hide();
            } else {
                parentDiv.find('.scrollRight', self).show();
            }
        }
```

That way you are still only selecting by class, but you are limiting the elements jQuery is selecting from to the sub-tree of parentDiv.

Barring any JS scoping issues, that should work. If you run into scoping issues, you probably need to refactor the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. There may be a scoping issue with the setScrollButtons() function or event handlers

Comment: Are you using a JS debugger? I'm curious to know if parentDiv gets the correct element and if so, does setScrollButtons also get an element obj or does it get a null value?

Comment: I put the code online here: http://stephentang.info/testing/belt-test2.html  I'm using Firebug, and the parentDIV show div.belt but I cannot determine which div.belt it sees.  If you go to my page, you will see that the second carousel works correctly, but the first carousel does not.

Comment: I'm checking out your code now, it's getting the proper div each time, the issue has to do with the closure that holds the "currentPage" variable. Rather than keep it in the closure, I cheat and hide these values in the dom. For example, you can set $(this).attr("currentPage", "1") instead of setting currentPage = 1 in the variable initialization section. Then in the click event, once you get parentDiv, you can do var currentPage = parseInt(parentDiv.attr("currentPage"))++; parentDiv.attr("currentPage", currentPage); This is a quick workaround. If you have time, figure out the closure issue.

Comment: [I ran out of space] My workaround isn't very clean but if you're in a pinch it should work. I highly recommend reading up on javascript closures to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation.  The issue is not urgent for me, so I will want to figure out a clean way to do this.  It's odd, because I thought the return this.each(function() {}) line would have a created separate variable instances for each div.belt.  From your investigation, it sounds like currentPage is a single instance for both div.belt, which is not what I had in mind.  Thanks for giving me a starting point to research further.

Comment: Sure thing. If you add a third "belt", you'll only see that third one working properly as well. It's definitely a closure issue. Please post the solution here once you've figured it out because now I'm curious!

Comment: In doing some more reading up on Javascript, I found this jQuery method http://api.jquery.com/data for storing data in the DOM as I described. I guess it's not cheating after all! 

Be sure to read the whole page, as it discusses an issue that plagues many sites - circular references.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard the term 'belt' for that. It's usually referred to as a carousel.

That said, in jQuery, you'd instantiate each one by selecting it individually (either via a unique ID, or a CSS3 selector, or grabbing all of them and traversing through them in jQuery) and then pass the settings/variables for each as you go.

So, instead of:

```
$('.belt').globalbelt();
```

I'd suggest:

```
$('#belt1').globalbelt();
$('#belt2').globalbelt();
$('#belt3').globalbelt();
```

Comment: The requirements we have previously received were called "belts" so I just stuck with that.  Unfortunately, I cannot use IDs here, because in the CMS, this belt/carousel is simply a component.  The end user can instantiate a template and add any number of this component.  I am trying to find out if this can be done without using IDs.

Comment: FYI, if it's any easier, there are several jQuery Carousel plugins already out there. http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I have seen some of those plug-ins before, but we decided to write something simple for our website, so we can skin it easier.  We do not need the additional functionality that most of these other plug-ins provide, and some are a bit more difficult to skin.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for both the belts responding is because the code binds to both the clicks.

In the function for designated event handlers to scroll left, specify the target as the div where the event occurs. The current code does not have that "context" information.

change the event handlers to

```
$('.scrollLeft a', self).click(function(event){
      self = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
      currentPage--;
      setScrollButtons();
      $('ul', self).animate({ left: '+=' + pageWidth }, shiftDuration);
      return false;
});
```

This will work as expected.

Comment: I thought using the 'self' context in the selector for the click event would have worked $('.scrollLeft a', self).click(function(event), because self should refer to the current div being targeted.